# CSS - How to create a title background with a circle and a line-gradient?

Tags: css, background, html

I want to create a title with a background like this:

[image]

But there is a problem, as you can see in the picture, there are 3 different backgrounds:

- The first one is for the whole page
- second one is just a circle
- third is a black line.

I want to create this title but i have problems with backgrounds.

I've tried including Span tag into title `h3` ... didn't work.
what should I do?
P.S: I want to make this background for all titles backgrounds, so I don't want to create just one background for one title, I want it to be responsive and look good on any title.

Comment: `i've tried including Span tag into title h3`, what code did you come up with when you tried?

Comment: I'm confused - why can't you just put the circle/line thinggy in a transparent png and put that as a background on your `h3`

Answer (score 3):

the markup   [image]

```
 <h3>Meet the Team</h3>
```

the style

```
h3{
    width:320px;
    height:40px;
    text-align:left;
    background:black;
    color:red;
    padding:10px;
    line-height:40px;
    position:relative;
}

h3:before,h3:after{
    position:absolute;
    content:'';
}
h3:before{
   width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    background: #2C2C2C;
    right: 174px;
    top: 20px;
    box-shadow: inset -2px -1px #3F3D3D;    
}

h3:after{
    width:160px;
    height:4px;
    background:red;
    background: #2C2C2C;
    right: 14px;
    top: 28px;
    box-shadow: inset -2px -1px #3F3D3D; 
}
```

Demo:http://jsfiddle.net/9U8NQ/

Comment: How can i make it responsive ? because there is some different titles with different widths , i want to make it responsive to fill the parent column of title .
PS : The template's framework is Bootstrap .
thank you .

Comment: i know , i want to use percentages but i don't know where . when i use percentages for width , the div disappears .

Comment: h3:after you can change the width and the position as you want. Same for h3:before